# Compare BASH variable to string

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, compare

I am very new to BASH scripting and am trying to write a program that will compare a command the user inputs, to a list of options. Here is my program so far:

```
echo "enter command"
read command
if ["$command" = "quit"]
then
    exit
fi
```

when I run this, I get the following error:

```
./script.sh: line 3: [quit: command not found
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you are writing `["$command"`. Just add a space after `[` and before `"$command"`.

Comment: Thank's a lot, that fixed it!